# Plotly combined barplot and table controled by range slider

Tags: python, slider, plotly, range

I'm currently trying to create a graph with plotly,

My goal would be to create a combined **Barplot / Data table** both controled with a range slider in order to controle the values with the date. I've succeded to create the barplot controled with the range slider.

I can't manage to control the table :/

Here is a combined plot but where the range slider is attached to the table, as you can see it does not control the date but the table view
[https://plotly.com/~tristan1551/31/](https://plotly.com/%7Etristan1551/31/)

Here is an exemple of a barplot i've done with a range slider [https://plotly.com/~tristan1551/23/](https://plotly.com/%7Etristan1551/23/)

Another idea would be to only  to control the table with the ranger slider, i can't manager to do that too.

Is there a way to achive what i want to do ?

Thank you for your herlp :)

Answer (score 2):

- to synchronise a table with a range slider on a figure you can use a **dash callback**
- below code creates a bar chart with a **rangeslider**
- attaches a callback to changes in **figure** to get position of **rangeslider**
- constructs table based on these inputs

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_apple_stock.csv")
df["AAPL_x"] = pd.to_datetime(df["AAPL_x"])

fig = px.bar(df, x="AAPL_x", y="AAPL_y").update_layout(
    xaxis={
        "range": [df["AAPL_x"].quantile(0.9), df["AAPL_x"].max()],
        "rangeslider": {"visible": True},
    }
)

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [dcc.Graph(id="bargraph", figure=fig), html.Div(id="bartable", children=[])],
)


@app.callback(
    Output("bartable", "children"),
    Input("bargraph", "relayoutData"),
)
def updateTable(graphData):
    global df
    if graphData and "xaxis.range" in graphData.keys():
        d1 = pd.to_datetime(graphData["xaxis.range"][0])
        d2 = pd.to_datetime(graphData["xaxis.range"][1])
    else:
        d1 = df["AAPL_x"].quantile(0.9)
        d2 = df["AAPL_x"].max()
    dft = df.loc[df["AAPL_x"].between(d1, d2)]
    return dash_table.DataTable(
        columns=[{"name": c, "id": c} for c in dft.columns],
        data=dft.to_dict("records"),
    )


# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode="inline")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that was what i wanted to do, i'm now trying to use a csv instead. But i can't manage to make it work like your code. For instance how could i use this CVS ( https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_apple_stock.csv ) ? for the raw data ?

Comment: @TristanMarrié updated answer to use your sample data.  just need to refer to column names correctly